# How to go about creating an automated 'web crawler', which can record URLs and other data in a document?

Tags: javascript, python, regex, automation

I hope that I'm keeping on topic. If not, please let me know, as this is the first question I've posted here!

What do I need to know to create a programme which automatically records websites visited by me (or any other individual), and transfers these into a document? I'm assuming this application could be built using JavaScript or Python? Could I incorporate regular expressions?

I suppose I'm sort of describing a web crawler, only with additional features?

Comment: you can make use of browser history , which can be accessed in javascript

Comment: You might be able to achieve this with ScraperWiki https://classic.scraperwiki.com/

Comment: Thanks for comments. ScraperWiki looks very interesting too!

Comment: You could use your web connection via a proxy, which captures the pages you have accessed. That creates log files, which can then be read using something like Python.